# error in calculation of relative frequency of groups based on different combinations

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

I would like to calculate the frequency and relative frequency of the categorical variables based on different combinations. I have calculated the frequency and was not successful in piping the output to the relative frequency calculation. Could someone help me in identifying the error ?

```
# Random generation of values for categorical data
set.seed(33)
df <- data.frame(cat1 = sample( LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace=TRUE ), 
                cat2 = sample( LETTERS[3:5], 100, replace=TRUE ),
                cat3 = sample( LETTERS[2:4], 100, replace=TRUE ),
                var1 = sample( LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace=TRUE ), 
                var2 = sample( LETTERS[3:8], 100, replace=TRUE ),
                var3 = sample( LETTERS[2:3], 100, replace=TRUE ),
                vre1 = sample( LETTERS[2:7], 100, replace=TRUE ), 
                vre2 = sample( LETTERS[1:5], 100, replace=TRUE ),
                ref3 = sample( LETTERS[2:9], 100, replace=TRUE ),
                con1 = runif(100,0,100),
                con2 = runif(100,23,45))

# Calculating the frequency
library(dplyr)
cat.names <- c('var1','var3','vre2','ref3')
df %>% group_by(cat1, cat3) %>% summarise_each(funs(n = n()), one_of(cat.names))

# Piping it to calculate the relative frequency/Percentage
df %>% group_by(cat1, cat3) %>% summarise_each(funs(n = n()), one_of(cat.names)) %>% mutate(freq = n / sum(n))

# Error
Error: invalid 'type' (closure) of argument

#Expected Output
    cat1    cat3    var1.freq   var3.freq   vre2.freq   ref3.freq   var1.rfreq  var3.rfreq  vre2.rfreq  ref3.rfreq
1   A   B   8   8   8   8   0,153846154 0,153846154 0,153846154 0,153846154
2   A   C   27  27  27  27  0,519230769 0,519230769 0,519230769 0,519230769
3   A   D   17  17  17  17  0,326923077 0,326923077 0,326923077 0,326923077
4   B   B   16  16  16  16  0,333333333 0,333333333 0,333333333 0,333333333
5   B   C   12  12  12  12  0,25    0,25    0,25    0,25
6   B   D   20  20  20  20  0,416666667 0,416666667 0,416666667 0,416666667
```

Comment: Here the column names are still var1 var3 vre2 ref3.  Check the output of `df %>% group_by(cat1, cat3) %>% summarise_each(funs(n = n()), one_of(cat.names))`  By calling `mutate(freq=n/sum(n))`, which column are you aiming for?

Comment: @akrun Yeah, I could observe that. I have tried to pass each variable in `cat.names` for `mutate` as well but I wasn't successful.

Comment: Perhaps `df %>% group_by(cat1, cat3) %>% summarise_each(funs(n()/nrow(df)), one_of(cat.names))`  It would be better to have expected output

Comment: Are you looking for frequency of unique elements per each group?  In that case, `n_distinct` may be useful. i.e. `df %>% group_by(cat1, cat3) %>% summarise_each(funs(n_distinct(.)/n()), one_of(cat.names))`

Comment: @akrun No, I am looking for frequency of elements for each group and its percentage share.

Comment: 8/(8+27+17)=0.153846154

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82171/discussion-between-prradep-and-akrun).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 df1 <- df %>%
          group_by(cat1, cat3) %>%
          summarise_each(funs(n()), one_of(cat.names))
 df2 <- df1 %>%
            group_by(cat1) %>% 
            mutate_each(funs(./sum(.)), var1:ref3)
 bind_cols(df1, df2[-(1:2)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using `data.table`:

```
result<-df[,.(fr.v1=sum(table(var1)),fr.v2=sum(table(var2))),
    by=.(cat1,cat3)][,prop.v1:=fr.v1/sum(fr.v1),by=cat1]
```

For simplicity, I'm only calculating frequencies for `var1` and `var2`, but extending the code is simple.